# Exterior Security Camera Base?

Tags: security

My exterior camera system uses this particular cover to hide wired on the siding. We're changing the cameras over to a more modern type (And some of the cameras are defective over their > 15 year use)

What is it, and can I purchase it at home depot or similar stores?

Pictured at the base of the camera:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a standard vinyl siding [mounting block](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Builders-Edge-6-625-in-x-6-625-in-001-White-Surface-Mounting-Block-130110006001/100684069?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-NA-_-100684069-_-N).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was most likely a trim piece that a professional installer had access to or even something that the camera company made at the time.  I'm not an expert or camera installer, but I know my way around Home Depot and dabble in home security and I haven't seen this item commonly sold.  If you look at more "pro level" catalogs targeted at installers you might find something.

That said, why can't you re-use the existing parts you have?  It doesn't look like they have an extremely large hole or anything?  A good cleaning and coat of paint should be enough to make them as good as new.